# ifelse() halts execution, despite seeming to complete correctly

Tags: r

Disclaimer: I'm trying to make someone else's code more user friendly and I'm pretty new to R, so if you see me using mismatched coding conventions, that's why.

I'm trying to write my script's status to the terminal as it goes through a list of files, checking to make sure they are valid before using them as input to a model.  Therefore, I need to pass a variable (filename) and status ("looks good") to a function that will concatenate them and write them to the terminal in green.  When I test the function like so, it works:

```
say <- function(words){
  cat(green(words))
}

hi <- "Hello"

say(c(hi, "World!"))
# Hello World!
```

But when I call say() from within the ifelse() that I need to call it from, I get an error I cannot decipher:

```
FileList = as.data.frame(list.files(path = "./R_ModelInputs_SecondaryData",
                                    pattern = ".tif$", all.files = FALSE,
                                    full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
                                    ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE))
names(FileList)=c("FileName")

for(NAME in FileList$FilName){
  data=raster(paste("./R_ModelInputs_SecondaryData/",NAME,sep=""))

  ifelse(nrow(data)!=1737,
         say(c(NAME, "has a problem"),
         ifelse(ncol(data)!=4008,
                say(c(NAME, "has a problem")),
                say(c(NAME, "looks good"))
         ))
}
# Goode_FireBrightness_80_10kMax_20002015.tif  looks goodError in ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test &
# :
#  replacement has length zero
# Calls: ifelse -> ifelse
# In addition: Warning message:
# In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
#   'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
# Execution halted
```

I've tried googling this error but all I've come up with is that it seems to be from the ifelse() call.  This doesn't make sense to me because the fact that it's writing the "looks good" part means that it's successfully navigated both ifelse()'s.  I inserted a print() statement at the top of the for loop to ensure that it wasn't throwing the error when it tried to evaluate the ifelse() in the second iteration of my for loop, but that's not what it is, as that print() statement only printed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse()` should be used when you want to return a vector. It expects to return a vector the same length as your first parameter. Your `say()` function is returning the value from `cat()` which just returns `NULL`. There's no way to make NULL the same length as your test condition. This is throwing the `ifelse` off.

`ifelse` should not be used for control flow logic. You should be using a standard `if/else` here for conditional code execution.

Use

```
if(nrow(data)!=1737) {
  say(c(NAME, "has a problem") 
} else if (ncol(data)!=4008) {
  say(c(NAME, "has a problem"))
} else {
  say(c(NAME, "looks good"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do this in a more R-y way like this

```
ff <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
r <- lapply(ff, raster)
x <- t(sapply(r, dim))
good <- x[,1] == 1737 & x[,2] == 4008
# good
basename(ff)[good]
# problem
basename(ff)[!good]
```